# Нужно выполнить множественный поиск в Гугле по списку

Tags: javascript, python, google-search

Есть текстовый список (в данном случае большой список фильмов) и есть задача, сделать множественный список в Гугле по каждой строчке и выдать по каждой строчке ответ - самая первая ссылка в поисковой ленте (например на Википедию или любой другой сайт). Назначение: нажав на ссылку (например ведущую на Википедию) рядом с названием фильма, быстро узнать краткое описание фильма. Буду признателен если подскажите сервис, что может выполнить задачу, или например готовый алгоритм.